# CSS Tables & min-width container?

Tags: css, css-tables

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="sidebar">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

#wrapper { min-width: 900px; }
#main { display: table-row; }
#content { display: table-cell; }
#sidebar { display: table-cell; width: 250px; }
```

The problem is that the sidebar isn't always at the right-most part of the page (depending on the width of `#content`). As `#content`'s width is variable (depending on the width of the window), how to I make it so that the sidebar is always at the right-most part of its parent?

---

Example:

Here's what I have now:

```
<---  variable window width   ---->
 ---------------------------------
| (header)                        |
 ---------------------------------
 [content]  | [sidebar] |
            |           |
            |           |
            |           |
            |           |
            |           |
            |           |
```

And here's what I want:

```
<---  variable window width   ---->
 ---------------------------------
| (header)                        |
 ---------------------------------
 [content]           | [sidebar] |
                     |           |
                     |           |
                     |           |
                     |           |
                     |           |
                     |           |
```

---

Please let me know if you need anymore information to help me with this issue. Thanks!

PS - I know I can accomplish this easily with floats. I'm looking for a solution that uses CSS tables.

---

SOLUTION:

```
#wrapper { min-width: 900px; }
#main { display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
#content { display: table-cell; }
#sidebar { display: table-cell; width: 250px; }
```

No need to declare a `table-row` element, thanks to [anonymous table elements](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the style `display: table` (or `inline-table`) on a wrapper div around `#main` in order for the other table display types to make sense; it's undefined what happens if you put rows inside something that's not a table.

Then on that wrapper you'd have to also set `table-layout: fixed;` to make the browser actually respect the widths you specify (in the first table-row, if you don't have explicit columns). Otherwise you get the auto table layout algorithm second-guessing you. Finally add `width: 100%;` to avoid shrink-to-fit.

> I'm looking for a solution that uses CSS tables.

Any reason for that, or is this just an exercise? CSS tables aren't a good choice today due to poor browser support and in the end they don't really get you anything over just using a table. CSS positioning would seem to be the better way to go for simple layouts like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll play around with it and let you know how it works for me. About the CSS tables comment: I like future-proofing my sites, and a little more work today saves me that much more in the future. "In the end", the do honor semantic HTML markup and make for simplified stylesheet rules: I think that's reason enough right there. The only major player that doesn't currently support them is IE7 & IE6; all other releases of currently used browsers can render them just fine.  Gotta push that envelope if things are going to change at all!

Comment: Slightly-amended solution appended to my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Set the parent to position:relative. Then set the sidebar to position:absolute and snug it to the right.

So....

```
#main{
position:relative;
}

#sidebar{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
}
```

That should keep your sidebar snug to the right of main, regardless of how wide content is.

Comment: -1: what if the main isn't as high as the sidebar, what happens to the footer? Also, OP wants tables. If anything worked, he'd use floats.

Comment: He didn't say anything about the sidebar needing to be higher than the main content, nor did he say anything about a footer. But thanks for the -1, griefer.